# MVC 4 Global Exception Filter how to implement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I implement a global exception handler in  MVC4 as it seems to be different from MVC3.

Not sure how to implement the following:

```
public class ErrorHandlerAttribute: System.Web.Mvc.FilterAttribute, 
                                    IExceptionFilter
{
    public Task ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(
            HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This guy has a pretty good walkthrough on how to make a global exception handler in MVC: http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately the link provided in Eric Leschinski's commet only shows how to implement the [System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iexceptionfilter%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) interface, and not the [System.Web.Http.Filters.IExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.http.filters.iexceptionfilter%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) interface. The first is used in regular MVC controllers, while the second targets [ApiCotrollers](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

Here is a simple class example I came up with for logging unhandled exceptions thrown in my ApiControllers:

```
public class ExceptionLoggerFilter: IExceptionFilter
{
    public ExceptionLoggerFilter(Logger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return true; } }

    public Task ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(
            HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            logger.Error("web service error", actionExecutedContext.Exception);
        }, cancellationToken);
    }

    private Logger logger;
}
```

And all you have to do to enable this filter is register it in yours Global.asax Application_Start method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // allocate filter and add it to global configuration
    var exceptionLogger = new ExceptionLoggerFilter(Container.Get<Logger>());
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(exceptionLogger);

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

I hope this helps other googlers out there!

Comment: You may also implement applcation_Error in global.asax file if that works for you

Comment: Why do you call Task.Factory.StartNew? is that the same as Task.Run? see http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: For no particular reason actually. Calling *Task.Run* is equivalent to *Task.Factory.StartNew* passing in some default parameters (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx). But you're right, since the *Task.Run* method was introduced in the .NET Framework 4.5 it has become the recommended way to schedule a task for execution.

Comment: When I try `filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilter());` in `RegisterGlobalFilters` FilterConfig.cs I get `The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter.`

Comment: I had to do `config.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilter());` in `WebApiConfig.cs`

Answer (score 11):

The way I created an exception handler for MVC part of it, I created a class that implemented IExceptionFilter

```
public class MVCExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(filterContext.Exception.ToString());
    }
}
```

You then register it in the Global.asax.cs
inside `protected void Application_Start()`

The method already contains the line

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

So, you will need to add this line **ABOVE** it

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MVCExceptionFilter());
```

Comment: I also have both MVC and API Controllers, so I needed to implement both filters, they essentially do the same, so I factored that our into a service class.