# using filter to handle errors mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have numerous method which I call using jquery ajax.

In order to handle any errors in the fail method I use the following code;

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateStockTransactionAsync(
        string TransactionDate, string Quantity, string ProductId, string TabCount)
    {
        try
        {
            //my code goes here

        }
        catch (System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var errorModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AcknowledgementModel>(msg);
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, errorModel.errormessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I seem to be repeating this an awful lot throughout my code, is it possible to maybe pull this out to a filter attribute? if so how?

Comment: Does this need to be specific to the method's being called this way or global to all errors generated by the app?

Comment: This answer might help if you want a generic error handler :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831933/mvc-4-global-exception-filter-how-to-implement

Comment: I'm happy for a more generic approach on a filter, I just want to try and stop the repetative nature of the methods, however not all will be ajax calls so in some cases i handle errors and return error views etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the overridable method [OnException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onexception(v=vs.118).aspx) available on Controller class.

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    var exception = filterContext.Exception;

    if (exception is System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException) // Catch HttpResponseException
    { 
        var msg = ex.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var errorModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AcknowledgementModel>(msg);
        filterContext.Result =  new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, errorModel.errormessage);
    }
    else // catch (Exception ex)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, ex.Message);
    }

    base.OnException(filterContext); 
}
```

You can redirect results with `filterContext.Result`

Comment: ok so in this case I would have to add this method per controller wouldn't? also would this trigger for every exception? as in the cases where my actions would return a view I would normally catch the error and reutnr an error view, so the error handling is slightly different.

Comment: You have to add it in every controller unless you have a common base controller. Yes this would trigger with every exception.

Comment: ok so I suppose I could use the following link with your above example code http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling I could then use the filter to decorate relevant methods. Do you know If it would be possible to sperate and handle the view errors in the same filter so I could simply decorate the class?